# Is there a workaround to use thin client with cache expiry policy in Apache Ignite?

Tags: c#, ignite

We are currently using Ignite 2.1/C# in our application and considering to 
use Ignite 2.5/C# because of thin client feature. But we notice that thin 
client doesn't support to create cache value with expiry policy dynamically. We use that feature heavily in our application.

To be specifically, you can create a cache with expiry policy as follows

```
var cache = cache.WithExpiryPolicy(new ExpiryPolicy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)));
```

I want to ask if there is any workaround for thin client to achieve the same thing.

Thanks

Comment: I have asked this question on the Ignite dev list: http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/Can-NET-thin-client-have-cache-expire-policy-td32573.html

Comment: There is an Ignite user-list thread for the same question: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Thin-client-doesn-t-support-Expiry-Policies-tt22422.html.